# Variable could access the property directly without the object got instantiated in C#

Tags: c#

```
static void CatAge(Cat cat) 
{
    cat.Age = 12;
}
class Cat
{
    public int Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
}
```

When we declare a Method, why the variable **cat** can access the property directly(**cat.Age**)  without the class **Cat** got instantiated?

Comment: Because the method takes an argument of type `Cat`, which might be initialized or not. In any case you can access that property because it's `public`, but you will get a `NullReferenceException` at runtime if the instance is `null`(not initialized).

Comment: Stop and think carefully what is `cat` in your method. What type it has? What value it has?

Comment: When you call `CatAge`, you'll pass an instantiated `Cat`. Otherwise, you'll be passing *NULL* and get a NRE.

Answer (score 1):

> why the variable cat can access the property directly(cat.Age) without the class Cat got instantiated

Because the method accepts an argument of `Cat`. You can supply the method with **an instance** or with `null`. In the latter case it will give you a `NullReferenceException`.

See here how to pass in an instance:

```
Cat cat = new Cat() { Age = 1 };

CatAge(cat); // see: cat is a variable which has an instance assigned to it
```